# Disable start menu on LWIN keypress

Tags: c#

The following code is to test the LWin keyup function in C# when the form is active. It's working fine and now when the form is active I need only the function alone has to take place and whenever I click on Lwin button start menu should not open. How can I achieve this?

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LWin)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Function working!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Try setting `e.Handled` to `True`.

Try the same thing with the `KeyPress` event. And the `KeyDown` event.

If these options don't work (and I suspect they won't), you've exhausted the options available to you in managed Windows Forms. I can't immediately think of a solution using P/Invoke, but I think that's the avenue you'll have to explore.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the OPs question. His stated that he was receiving the key press, but needs to disable the opening of the Windows Start Menu. Your answer was explaining how to get the key press, nothing about disabling the start menu.

Comment: From the documentation for the Handled property on KeyPressEventArgs: "If the event is not handled, it will be sent to the operating system for default processing. Set Handled to true to cancel the KeyPress event." If this is true, it will stop the start menu appearing. I suspect that the Windows key is a special case, though, hence the rest of the answer!

Comment: My apologies. I am not super familiar with C# at this point and misunderstood your answer based on that.

Comment: No worries. I should have been more clear on the purpose of my suggestion. :)

Comment: If you make an edit to your answer I can remove my down vote which has been locked :(